# how to set same date first text box to second text box when field in counter?

Tags: javascript

*I am giving date in first line by date picker but i want same date in second line on mouse click but how to find 2nd line id of `delivery date` and  set the value of 1st line*

```
<input type="text" name="deliveryDate<%=i%>" id="deliveryDate<%=i%>" maxlength="10" style="text-align: left; width:70px" onchange="return checkDt(this);" />
```

Comment: which date picker? more details pls

Comment: <a href="javascript:NewCssCal('deliveryDate<%=i%>','ddmmyyyy')"><img src="images/cal.gif" width="18" height="17" border="0" alt="Pick a date">

Comment: user can take date fron datepicker and also fill in text box ......bt how can take 1 line to second line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZLkr2/

**HTML**

```
<form action="demo.html" id="myForm">
    <p>
        <label>First date:</label>
         <input type="text" id="deliveryDate1" maxlength="10" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Second date:</label>
         <input type="text" id="deliveryDate2" maxlength="10" />
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    // React on every change event of the deliveryDate1
    $("#deliveryDate1").on("propertychange keyup input paste",null,function(){
        //Put the deliveryDate1 value into the deliveryDate2 field
        $("#deliveryDate2").val($(this).val());
    })
});
```

Comment: i m taking text field id by counter deliveryDate <%=i%> so to set line 2 deliveryDate?

Comment: Nicolas Henrard ### but i want on mouse click what i changed in jquery function.